# Fibonacci with a twist

Tags: c

Im trying to write a code that computes Fibonacci with a few minor changes.
there's a limit to the number of iterations, there is a goal number and every i iterations the number is divided by 2.

somehow my code does not work properly.
it only works for lim = 1
in all other cases it does not do anything

can anyone see the bug?

```
int main()
{
    int i, lim, gen_num, 
        fib1, fib2, next, count = 0, iterations = 0;

    printf("Please enter the desired population\n");
    scanf("%d", &lim);
    printf("Please enter the number of generations alowd\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Please enter the number of generations between each disaster\n");
    scanf("%d", &gen_num);
    fib1 = 0;
    fib2 = 1;
    while (fib2 < lim);
    {
        if (iterations <= i)
        {
            next = fib1 + fib2;
            fib1 = fib2;
            fib2 = next;
            count += 1;
            iterations += 1;
            if (count%gen_num == 0)
            {
                fib2 /= 2;
            }
            printf("%d ", fib2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Number of iterations exceeded\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: "*does not work properly*" is not really informative. If you want help, describe your exact problem.

Comment: Your `while` loop has a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
while (fib2 < lim);
```

is an infinite loop when `fib2` is less than `lim`. The semicolon at the end means that you have an empty statement as the body of the loop, it's equivalent to:

```
while (fib < lim) {
}
```